# Find text in textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, search, text, find

Say a web page has a textbox with text inside of it. I want to find the first textbox and then retrieve its text. How would I go about this using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').eq(0).val()
```

Explain:

1. $(..) gets a set of DOM objects
2. eq(0) gets the first one in the set
3. val() gets the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('input:text:first').val();
```